# How to pass contextual filters in customer profile empty text?

Tags: views

I have a view displaying customer profiles. It takes 2 contextual filters : the user id and the type of the customer profile (billing/shipping). I want to add a no results behaviour, the "Commerce customer profile : Empty text". I filled in the field "Path to a customer profile add form" with something like /user/%/addressbook/%/create in order to have the % replaced with the contextual filters but it doesn't work. When I click on the link, I get the page "/user/%25/addressbook/%25/create" not found. I tried many things but in vain... Isn't this the way to pass contextual filters ? Thanks for your help !